# Find the no. of three element set of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ satisfying the $abc = 2310$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the no. of three element set of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ satisfying the $abc = 2310$

Here is  a solution

My question:  why we divide the first two cases by $2$ and didn't do that  for the other cases

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure where the three  triples like  $(2310,1,1)$ are being counted.

Comment: The solution is wrong, since no repeated case is being counted. $(a,b,c)$ is considered to be ordered pair, where $(2,3,385)$ and $(3,2,385)$ are different.

Comment: It looks to me like the first expression counts the triples in which two elements are prime and the third takes up the rest.  You divide by $2$ because the triple $\{p,q,r\}$ is the same as $\{q,p,r\}$.  Similarly, the second expression counts the triples in which one factor is prime and the other two are products of two primes.  You divide by $2$ because the triple $\{p,r,s\}$ is the same as $\{p,s,r\}$.  The third counts triples in which one term is a product of three primes, another is a product of two primes and the last factor is $1$.  No symmetry.

Comment: The fourth counts triples in which one term is prime, another is the product of four primes, and the third is $1$.  Again, no symmetries.  As I said, I think you are forgetting triples like $(2310,1,1)$.  It isn't clear whether you want to consider order as relevant or not.  Your notation suggests ordered triples, but then you appear to calculate unordered triples.  You should clarify.

Comment: @lulu But $(2,3,385)$ and $(3,2,385)$ are different, as far as order is concerned.

Comment: @JaideepKhare  From the calculation, I suspect the OP would say that they are the same.  I agree with you that the notation $(a,b,c)$ should only be used when order is important.  In any case, the OP should indicate which is intended.

Comment: The question should be - " Find the number of combinations of three natural numbers, that together multiply to $2310$"

Comment: @lulu  i think the word " set "indicates that the demand is distinct triples

Comment: @prayersmith oops.  You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions (which isn't how I would have done it) is saying:

There are 5 prime for factors: $p,q,r,s,t$

a) First count the the number of ways to do it were two of the numbers have one prime factor and the third has three. i.e $a = p; b = q; c =rst$

There are ${5 \choose 1}$ way of selecting $a = p$ from $p,q,r,s,t$.  There are ${4\choose 1}$ ways of selecting $b= q$ from $q,r,s,t$. and there is ${3 \choose 3}$ ways of choosing $c = rst$ from $r,s,t$.

Now choosing $a=p$ and $b=q$ is essentially the same as choosing $a = q$ and $b=p$ (or in other words "the order of choosing $a$ and $b$ doesn't matter").  So we divide by $2!$ as there are $2!$ ways to choose $a$ and $b$.

b) Then count the number of ways so that two have two prime factors and the third has 1.  i.e. if $a = pq; b=r; c=st$ (Frankly that ordering seems pervese to me-- I'd have chosen $a=pq; b=rs; c = t$-- but it doesn't matter as the answer will be the same.)

There are ${5\choose 2}$ ways to select $a$ and ${3\choose 1}$ ways for $b$ and ${2\choose 2}$ ways for $c$.

Again the order of choosing $a$ or $c$ are interchangable as they both have two factors.  So we divide by $2!$.

(FWIW $\frac {{5 \choose 2}{3 \choose 1}{2\choose 2}}{2!} = \frac {{5 \choose 2}{3 \choose 2}{1\choose 1}}{2!}$)

c) Then count the number of ways one number can have three factors and a second has one. i.e $a = pqr; b=st; c =1$.

There are ${5\choose 3}$ ways to choose $a=pqr$ and ${3 \choose 2}$ ways to choose $b=st$ and $1$ way to chose $c=1$

$a$ has three prime factors and $b$ has two (and $c$ has zero) and this time they are *not* interchangable so we *don't* divide by $2!$..

d) Count ways that one has four factors, another one factor.  i.e. $a = pqrs; b =t; c=1$.

The ${5 \choose 4}$ ways of selectting the four factors of one is not comparable to the ${1 \choose 1}$ way of selecting $b$.  So we do not divide by $2!$.

*BTW they forget the fifth option*

e) $a = pqrst; b=1; c=1$.  So the answer is $41$.

Oops.  No they didn't.  That would be a set of two numbers, not a distinct set of three.

====

Maybe it'd b clearer (but longer) if there were six factors

1) $a= pq;b=rs;c=tu$ so $\frac {{6\choose 2}{4\choose 2}{2\choose 2}}{3!}$

2) $a= pqr; b=st; c= u$ so ${{ 6\choose 3}{3\choose 1}{1\choose 1}}$

3) $a=pqr;b=stu;c=1$ so $\frac{{6\choose 3}{3\choose 3}}{2!}$

4) $a =pqrs;b=t;c=u$ so $\frac{{6\choose 4}{2\choose 1}{ 1\choose 1}}{2!}$

5) $a = pqrs; b= ut;c=1$ so ${6\choose 5}{2\choose 2}$

6) $a = pqrst; b = ; c =1$ so ${6\choose 5}$

Comment: Elegant Solution;  thank you from the heart

Answer (score 2):

Finding a triple $a, b, c$ that multiplies out to 2310 is the same as deciding which one of $a, b$ and $c$ will have each of the factors $2, 3, 5, 7, 11$.

So the four numbers here

$${{5 \choose 1} {4 \choose 1} {3 \choose 3} \over 2!}, {{5 \choose 2}{3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 2} \over 2!}, {5 \choose 3} {2 \choose 2}, {5 \choose 4}{1 \choose 1} $$

are intended to break those up into four sets based on how many prime factors the numbers $a, b, c$ have.  The first one,

$$ {{5 \choose 1} {4 \choose 1} {3 \choose 3} \over 2!} $$

counts those triples where one of $a, b, c$ has three factors and the other two have one each.  So for example we choose one of the five factors to go with $a$, one of the remaining four to go with $b$, and then all of the remaining three go with $c$.  For example we could have $a = 7, b = 3, b = 2 \times 5 \times 11 = 110$. But the numerator here double-counts - if you picked $a = 3, b = 7, c = 110$ that would be the same triple.  This explains the $2!$ in the denominator.   The same is true if the triple $a, b, c$ have 2, 2, and 1 factors -- for example $a = 2 \times 5 = 10, b = 11, c = 3 \times 7 = 21$.

The third and fourth numbers represent those triples where the three numbers have $3, 2$ and $0$ factors, or $4, 1$ and $0$ factors, so you don't have these double-counting issues.

As lulu has pointed out in a comment, this omits the possibility of triples where one of $a, b$ and $c$ is 2310 and the other two are one.  The problem as originally stated is ambiguous about whether these should be allowed, but the solution you've been given makes it clear that these should be omitted from the count.

Answer (score 1):

The reason fr dividing by $2$ is a double counting in the first two cases. Note the last binomial coefficient is useless: once $a$ and $b$ are chosen, $c$ is what remains.

**Hint:**

Since $2310=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdots5\cdot11,$ as many as the number of $3$-partitions of a set of $5$ elements.

Comment: (-1) OP isn't asking solution.He is asking why the first two cases are divided by $2!$.I downvoted because it isn't useful. I wonder why someone has upvoted.

Comment: This is only a hint for an argumentation, not a full solution.

Comment: Since you have added reason, I have removed my downvote